# Efficient way to color image regions with transparent overlay from a map of [1,0]

Tags: java, bitmap, overlay, transparency, jlayer

*I avoided the word bitmap in the title as bitmap in this context usually (?) refers to the bitmap from the underlying image.*

I have an image that is segmented into a number of different regions. For each region I have a map of ones and zeros (a bitmap) where 1 represents inside the region and zero outside the region. Not every part of the image is covered with a region, and the regions may overlap. The images are of the dimension (480x360).

What I would like to do is to overlay the image with a transparent red when you hoover the region with your mouse. My problem is that my current method is very slow and it takes a second or two before the overlay appears.

My current approach is using a JLayer over my ImagePanel (extension of JPanel drawing a BufferedImage). Then my instance of the LayerUI draws the overlay when the mouse is moved:

```
public class ImageHighlightLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {
    private boolean mouseActive;
    private Point mousePoint;
    private byte[][][] masks;

    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);

        if (mouseActive) {
            byte[][] curMask = null;

            // Find which region the mouse intersect
            for (int i = 0; i < masks.length; i++) {
                if (masks[i][mousePoint.x][mousePoint.y] == 1) {
                    curMask = masks[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Outside region --> don't draw overlay
            if (curMask == null) return;

            //Transparent red
            g.setColor(new Color((float)1.0, 
                            (float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.8));

            //Draw the mask
            for(int x = 0; x < curMask.length; x++) 
                for(int y = 0; y < curMask[y].length; y++) 
                    if (curMask[x][y] == 1) 
                       g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);

        }
    }
}
```

So, how can I make this more efficient? I open to suggestions using other ways than a JLayer. Can I use my bitmap in some "magic" way with some swing-method? Can I mix it with the underlying bitmap from the BufferedImage? Is removing transparancy the only thing that'll help me? (Which is something I would like to keep)

Two other side problems which are not necessarily related to the question, but I have yet to solve:

- The overlay is repainted every time the mouse moves. This seems like a waste of resources.
- When regions are overlapping, how do I choose which one to paint?